# How do I find grams of a compound if I have Molar Mass in Python?

Tags: python

I'm having some difficulty trying to convert from Molar Mass back to grams. This program spits out Molar Mass of Compound A at x grams(user input).
If I have 10grams of SiO2, then how much grams(respectfully), is Si and O2?

How would I code the user's input of let's say 10g SiO2 and convert it to how much needed g of Si and g of O?

10gSiO2 / M SiO2 * MSi = gSi

2*(10g SiO2 / M SiO2) * MO = gO (multiply by 2 because O2)

M = Molar Mass

g = grams

m = mole

```
import Periodic_Table_new as pt

print("Enter info for Compound A\n")
compoundA = pt.getInput()
gramTotal = float(input("Please enter total grams of Compound A: "))
moles = pt.convertToMoles(gramTotal,compoundA)
moleMass = moles/compoundA
print('\n')
print("The Molecular Mass of compound A at " + str(gramTotal) + "grams is : " + str(moleMass) + "\n\n")
```

Periodic_Table_new.py

```
def getInput():
    compoundName = "" 


ix = True
total = 0
while ix:

    elementName = str(input("Please Enter Element: "))

    amountNum = int(input("Please Enter Amount of Element: "))

    elementWeight = float(input("Please enter Element Weight: "))
    elementWeight = amountNum * elementWeight

    total = total + elementWeight

    compoundName = compoundName + elementName + str(amountNum)
    print(compoundName)

    userInput = input("Would you like to repeate? \n Y/N? ")

    if userInput == 'N' or userInput == 'n':
        ix = False
print(compoundName)
print(total)
return total

def convertToMoles(gOc,c):
moles = gOc/c
return moles

def molesToGrams():
p = moles * n * m
```

Comment: For the purpose of clarification, you're going to ask the user to enter a string that looks like `10g SiO2` and you want a function that will print `##g Si, ##g O`?

Comment: Basically I get the user to input Element (Si), Amount of element(1), Element Weight(28.085). I prompt the user if they would like to repeat(y/n) then continue for the next element until the user is finished. Sum the elements(Compound) and then ask for how many grams of compound the user desires. The total Molar Mass for 10gSiO2 would be 0.0027699241

Comment: I guess my question is, what are your results currently and how does that differ from the desired results? Also, welcome to SO. Please take some time to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: My results give me the g of the entire compound (example) SiO2. 
I need g of Si and g of O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a little bit of a different approach, based on my understanding of your desired results. This version is going to use a dictionary of atomic masses, regex to parse the compound string, and a loop to do the math. It's pretty flexible, but it requires you to build the dictionary of atomic masses, which shouldn't be hard, just a little tedious. It has some requirements for the input noted in the comments

```
import re

atomic_masses = {'Si': 28.0855, 'O': 15.999}

compound = input('Please enter a compound and amount: ')

amount_pat = re.compile(r'(\d+)g')  # compound mass must end in the letter g
element_pat = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]?\d*)')  # elemental symbols must be properly capitalized (Si, not si)
sym_pat = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]?')  # elemental symbols must be properly capitalized (Si, not si)
qty_pat = re.compile(r'\d+')

mass = int(amount_pat.search(compound)[1])

elements = []
# finds each element in the compound and makes a list of (element, parts) tuples
for element in element_pat.finditer(compound):
    element = element[0]
    symbol = sym_pat.search(element)[0]
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in element):
        qty = int(qty_pat.search(element)[0])
    else:
        qty = 1

    elements.append((symbol, qty))

# Calculates and prints total Molecular Mass for the compund
molecular_mass = sum(el[1] * atomic_masses[el[0]] for el in elements)
print(f'\nTotal Molecular Mass: {molecular_mass}\n')

# Calculates and prints the mass for each element
for tup in elements:
    unit_mass = (mass / molecular_mass) * atomic_masses[tup[0]] * tup[1]
    print(f'{tup[0]}: {unit_mass:.4f}g')
```

Example Output:

```
Please enter a compound and amount: 10g SiO2

Total Molecular Mass: 60.0835

Si: 4.6744g
O: 5.3256g
```

#### Edit:

In order to accommodate decimal mass for the input, we can change the regex inside `amount_pat` to `r'(\d*.\d+)g'`. Now it will accept values such as `.003g` or `0.003g`. It still does not take kg or mg, but if you lookup the built-in `re` package, you can get an idea how regex works and change it from there. [regex101](http://regex101.com) is also a good resource for regex, since it allows a trial and error approach to learning. I also changed `int` to `float` in the `mass` assignment statement

I did, however, change the elemental mass loop to adjust for mg and kg. If you wish to expand it further, just take the pattern I've started here and expand it further:

```
for tup in elements:
    unit_mass = (mass / molecular_mass) * atomic_masses[tup[0]] * tup[1]
    if unit_mass > 1000:
        unit_mass /= 1000
        unit = 'kg'

    elif unit_mass < .01:
        unit_mass *= 1000
        unit = 'mg'

    else:
        unit = 'g'

    print(f'{tup[0]}: {unit_mass:.4f}{unit}')
```

New Example Output:

```
Please enter a compound and amount: .003g H2O

Total Molecular Mass: 18.01488

H: 0.3357mg
O: 2.6643mg
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, very good looking code.
I enter in 0.003g H2O and it gives me something that doesn't look like the right answer.
H: 0.3357g
O: 2.6643g
I don't think it's factoring in the decimal point or something correctly? Your thoughts? Maybe shift everything over to the left?
I think it should be giving some very small/large numbers if you enter in milligrams, kilograms, grams, etc.

Comment: I'll update my answer to make it accept decimal grams.

Comment: Ok, thank you Eric! I have a final question haha. What happens when you have parenthesis in the equation...(NH4)3PO4...or...Al(NO3)3....Thank you for your help!

Comment: Right now, it doesn't account for the parenthesis. Writing those as N3H12PO4 or AlN3O9 will get the calculations right. Likewise, if there are formulas with the same element repeated in them, like the formula for Alkanes on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_group#Hydrocarbons), the formula will need to be reduced to simply contain each element, followed by the total amount of that element in the compound. If we wanted to account for parenthesis, we could add another regex pattern that looks for parenthesis and accommodate the multiplier in the element list loop.

Comment: If we wanted it to account for formulas like the Alkanes, we could make a subclass of `dict` that implements `__missing__` and use it to sum the values from each occurrence of that element.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the elements at the end, that is the missing part.

Without the input magic, here is an example for 10g SiO2:

```
target=10
elem=[['Si',1,28.09],['O',2,16]]

total=0
for e in elem:
  total=total+e[1]*e[2]
print('molar mass of compound:',total)

moles=target/total
print('moles:',moles)

for e in elem:
  print(e[0],moles*e[1],'mol',moles*e[1]*e[2],'g')
```

Comment: Would this go in the main file or the Periodic Table file? And would this require to code in the element name and not rely on the user input?

Comment: @ChristopherCamillucci it shows the calculation only. You can build the input ("target" and "elem") re-using your existing code. Just instead of solely calculating "total" (which is also "total" in your code), you also have to store the elements separately. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html if you need help with building lists

Comment: @ChristopherCamillucci by the way, you can just run this code as it is now (I am not sure if that was obvious or not)

Answer (score 0):

**Computing the Molar Mass and Mass Percentage of Elements within a Compound**

I used the [pyvalem](https://pypi.org/project/pyvalem/) package to achieve your desired output.
Here is my code

```
from pyvalem.formula import Formula
import numpy as np

def give_compound_details(compound, given_gram):

    # Dictionary of element of mole of a compound
    ele_mol_dict = Formula(compound).atom_stoich

    # Create a list comprehensioon to get the mass per ele
    mass_per_ele = [Formula(ele).mass * ele_mol_dict[ele] for ele in ele_mol_dict.keys()]

    # Create dic for ele and mass
    ele_mass_dict = dict(zip(list(Formula(compound).atom_stoich),mass_per_ele))

    # Create a list comprehension and dictionary for mass percentage per element of a compound
    ele_percent_mass_dict = dict(zip(list(ele_mol_dict.keys()),[(ele_mass_dict[ele] / Formula(compound).mass * 100) for ele in ele_mass_dict.keys()]))

    
    print(f"Total Molecular mass of {compound}: {Formula(compound).mass} g\n")  
    for key, value in ele_mass_dict.items():
        print(f"Molar Mass of {key}: {value} g")
    print("")
    for key, value in ele_percent_mass_dict.items():
        print(f"Mass Percentage of {key}: {round(value,2)} %")

    print("")
    print(f"If molecular mass of {compound} is {given_gram} g, therefore")

    for key, value in ele_percent_mass_dict.items():
        print(f"Mass of {key}: {round((value/100)*given_gram,4)} g")

# MAIN PROGRAM
is_running = True
while is_running:
    print("Computing the Molar Mass and Mass Percentage of Elements within a Compound")
    print("")
    compound = input("Compound: ")
    given_gram = float(input(f"How much {compound} do you have in grams? "))
    print("\nRESULT\n")
    function = give_compound_details(compound, given_gram)
    
    print("---------------------------------------")
    ask = input('Do you want to try again? \nType "y" is YES, type "n" if NO')
    if ask.islower() == 'n':
        is_running = False
    print("---------------------------------------")
```

Here is the sample output:
[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SZae.jpg)